# How to make git "see" a remote branch for a repo that was cloned with --single-branch?

Tags: git

I have a repository where git does not see origin/master. It was originally cloned out with the "--single-branch stable" option. This is a huge repository, and now I need to use origin/master as well. I don't want to re-clone the whole repo, because it is really huge, and it takes a lot of time.

Here are the remotes:

```
# git remote -v                                                                                                                                                              
origin  git@gitlab.not_telling.com:group_name/project_name.git (fetch)
origin  git@gitlab.not_telling.com:group_name/project_name.git (push)
```

Here is the first line of "git log":

```
commit 7e43bd67a31313ce6f09c79ce27f5a40026bf358 (HEAD -> master, tag: uat_2019-10-25, tag: stable_2019-10-25, origin/stable, stable)
```

Local branches known to git are `master` and `stable`. Remote branch known to git is `origin/stable`, but `origin/master` is missing.

If I try to reset stable to origin/master:

```
git checkout stable
git reset origin/master --hard
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

If I try to set upstream:

```
# git branch --set-upstream-to master origin/master                                                                                                                         
fatal: branch 'origin/master' does not exist
```

If I try to fetch:

```
# git checkout master && git fetch -v
Already on 'master'
From gitlab.not_telling.com:group_name/project_name
= [up to date]        stable     -> origin/stable
```

Also, if I try to list all branches with `git branch -a` then origin/master is not there:

```
* master
  stable
  remotes/origin/stable
```

How can I make git "know" about origin/master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a remote branch to the fetch list by editing your .git/config file and adding master to your remote "origin" section:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@gitlab.not_telling.com:group_name/project_name.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/stable:refs/remotes/origin/stable
    fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Then do a fetch:

```
git fetch origin
```

Now, origin/master should appear as a ref in your local repository. (You may still need to create your local master branch, if you need it).

Comment: I thought there will be a command line for this. But editing the config file is just as good.

Comment: There *is* a command-line way to do this—well, technically, more than one, but one Git command specifically does this: `git remote set-branch`. The `set-branch` sub-command of `git remote` has both "set" and "add" sub-modes, so `git remote set-branch --add master` should do the job. (That said, I actually prefer to just edit the config file myself :-) )